# OpenGL 'reshape()' function Viewport Border Background

Tags: c++, opengl, colors, viewport

I've created a window using Win32 in an OpenGL 3.2+ program and I'm experimenting with things.
Currently I'm using the `reshape()` function below to resize the window etc.

I've added a border within the viewport so it leaves a 50px border around the viewport which does what I was expecting.

```
    void reshape(int width, int height, int pers_Dist)
    {
      screenWidth = width;
      screenHeight = height;
      float border = 50;

      glViewport(0+border,0+border,width-(border*2),height-(border*2));

      MatrixRoutines<float>::perspective(pers_Dist, (GLfloat)screenWidth/(GLfloat)screenHeight, 1, 200, ProjectionMatrix);
    }
```

The background colour is set inside the `init()` function using: `glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);`, to black.

My question is, can the border be assigned a different colour to the background?
(if I change the colour, both the background and border are always the colour set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [scissor regions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40704/what-is-the-purpose-of-glscissor) to tell OpenGL where to clear:

1. `glDisable( GL_SCISSOR_TEST )`
2. Clear with border color
3. Set scissor to border region
4. `glEnable( GL_SCISSOR_TEST )`
5. Clear with inner color
6. Render scene